# Docker commands and setup running successfully yesterday started giving error "ENOENT" today suddenly on windows 10

Tags: docker, windows-10, docker-desktop

I am relatively new for the docker technology.

Yesterday I setup docker on windows 10 machine and ran few dockers.

Today I first used command "docker system prune" so that I can run all of it once again without any conflicts.

But now I am firing below command:

> docker run --name DockerName -v /c/collections:/etc/newman -t
>   postman/newman:ubuntu run
>   "MyAPITestCollection.postman_collection.json"
>   --environment="MyAPITestEnvironment.postman_environment.json" --reporters="json,cli" --reporter-json-export="reports/MyAPITestReport.json"

And getting below error:

```
error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'MyAPITestEnvironment.postman_environment.json'
```

I haven't made any changes to the directories or anything else.

I checked the docker desktop setup option and found that the drive on which the file is located is still showing as the shared drive.

I tried by restarting the docker desktop several times and once by rebooting the machine as well but still found same error.

Kindly requesting to help me figure out the root cause of this issue and the solution as well.

Comment: It is the exact error that you're getting? What is "fileName"?

Comment: @funnydman "fileName" is the name of the file which I am unable to access. I am updating the question with command so it may give more clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My docker network had once again become public so firewall might be preventing the file access.

I changed it to private by using below command and it ran successfully:

```
Set-NetConnectionProfile -interfacealias "vEthernet (DockerNAT)" -NetworkCategory Private
```